# Macro to generate element-wise methods

Tags: macros, closures, julia, julian-date

I see myself writing this pattern again and again, where a function can take an entity E or a iterator over Es and apply elementwise. eg:- an index or a vector. A column or a matrix. I was wondering if there is a macro so that I need not define multiple methods. I am looking for a julian way of doing this.

In the simplified version of my use case below, compare `getrow` which is naturally overloaded to work on `int`s or `slice`s with `innerprod` that needs to be redefined for `Vector`s and `Matrix`es.

```
type Mat{T<:Number}
  data::Matrix{T}
end

getrow{T}(m::Mat{T}, i=size(m)[1]) = m.data[i, :]
innerprod{T}(m::Mat{T}, v::Array{T}) = m.data*v
innerprod{T}(m::Mat{T}, vv::Matrix{T}) = mapslices(v->innerprod(m, v), vv, 1)


m = Mat(rand(1:9, 2, 3))
v = rand(1:9, 3, 4)
f = innerprod(m, v[:,1])
g = innerprod(m, v)
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are showing. Your `innerprod` function is just matrix multiplication, and works equally well for vectors and matrices. Why not just write `m.data * v`? Maybe you can show an example of something you _cannot_ do?

Comment: Furthermore, if you just define one single method: `innerprod{T<:Number}(m::Mat, v::Array{T}) = mapslices(x->m.data*x, v, 1)`, it will work for all array dimensions, and promote number types correctly, so you can mix `Int`s and `Floatxx`s and `Complex` and `Rational` and whatever. You could even call the method `*` instead of `innerprod`, so you could do `m * v`.

Comment: This also looks like a use case for broadcasting and https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl#scalar